# Get the ACF text field value from the category of a custom post type in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to create another class using the value of a text field from ACF PRO.

I have a custom post type named "portfolio" and it has a 4 categories, the ACF field setting is added to "taxonomy is equal to category".

When I edit a category I fill in the name that I want to get and then display like this :

```
<div class="grid-item-catalog catalog-project-Holder **the name need to be here**">
```

How do I get the ACF field value from the category?

Other information: my page template is page-portfolio.php and I am using an ACF repeater.

This is my code :

```
<!-- catalog -->
<div class="grid-catalog catalog-portfolio-wrraper">  
  <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) {  while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post(); ?>
     <!-- Repeater -->
     <?php if( have_rows('portfolio-projects-repeater') ){ ?>
        <?php while( have_rows('portfolio-projects-repeater') ) { the_row(); 
          // vars
          $projectDescription = get_sub_field('project-name');
          $projectImage = get_sub_field('project-image');
          $projectLinkText = get_sub_field('project-link-text');
          $projectLink = get_sub_field('project-link');                                                       
          ?> 
             <div class="grid-item-catalog catalog-project-Holder {the name need to be here}"> 
                  <div class="catalog-project-name"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                  <div class="catalog-project-content-container">
                     <div class="catalog-project-image"><img src="<?php echo $projectImage['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $projectImage['alt'] ?>" /></div>
                     <div class="catalog-project-content">
                        <div class="description-link-container">
                             <div class="description"><?php echo $projectDescription; ?></div>
                             <div class="link"><a href="<?php echo $projectLink; ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><?php echo $projectLinkText; ?></a></div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <!-- End Repeater --> 
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
<!-- end catalog -->
```

This is a screenshot of the settings for the category's ACF field, I hope it helps:

[image: setup of the field]

Comment: I don't understand what field you are trying to get. Can you show us a screenshot of your ACF setup for the field?

Comment: i add a screenshot as you ask, i hope it is more clear now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a **custom post type "portfolio"** and you want to get the **ACF field value for the *categories* that the post belongs to**. These categories are in the **default Wordpress category** (i.e. not a custom taxonomy). This is to do with the post and not the values in your repeater.

If that is the case, you can get the value of the ACF field (`category-name`) for a category like this:

```
$category_name = get_field('category-name', $category_id);
```

This means we need to get the category ids for the post in your loop, and you can do this using `get_the_category` (assuming it is the default categories, for custom taxonomies you need `get_the_terms`). Also note that a post can have multiple categories so `get_the_categories` returns an array:

```
$category_classes = "";
// 1. GET THE CATEGORIES FOR THE CURRENT POST IN THE LOOP
$categories = get_the_category( get_the_ID()); 
if ( $categories ) {
    // 2. A POST CAN HAVE MULTIPLE CATEGORIES SO LOOP THROUGH THEM TO LOOK UP THE ACF FIELD
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        // 3. ADD ALL ACF VALUE FOR THIS CATEGORY TO OUR $category_classes VARIABLE, SEPARATED BY SPACES
        $category_classes .= " ".get_field('category-name', $category->term_id);
    }        
}
```

Now `$category_classes` will have a space-separated list of the ACF values for the categories that you can use directly in your `class` attribute, i.e.

```
<div class="grid-item-catalog catalog-project-Holder <?php echo $category_classes; ?>">
```

Putting this into your code, it should be something like this:

```
<!-- catalog -->
<div class="grid-catalog catalog-portfolio-wrraper">  
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) {  while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php
    /* YOUR CODE TO GET THE POST CATEGORIES AND LOOK UP THE ACF FIELD VALUE */
    $category_classes = "";
    // 1. GET THE CATEGORIES FOR THE CURRENT POST IN THE LOOP
    $categories = get_the_category( get_the_ID()); 
    if ( $categories ) {
        // 2. A POST CAN HAVE MULTIPLE CATEGORIES SO WE NEED TO LOOP THROUGH THEM ALL
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
            // 3. ADD ALL ACF VALUE FOR THIS CATEGORY TO OUR $category_classes VARIABLE, SEPARATED BY SPACES
            $category_classes .= " ".get_field('category-name', $category->term_id);
        }        
    }
    ?>

  <!-- Repeater -->
  <?php if( have_rows('portfolio-projects-repeater') ){ ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('portfolio-projects-repeater') ) { the_row(); 
      // vars
      $projectDescription = get_sub_field('project-name');
      $projectImage = get_sub_field('project-image');
      $projectLinkText = get_sub_field('project-link-text');
      $projectLink = get_sub_field('project-link');                                                       
      ?> 

         <?php 4. OUTPUT THE CLASSES FOR THE DIV ?>
         <div class="grid-item-catalog catalog-project-Holder <?php echo $category_classes; ?>"> 

         <!--   the rest of your code here   -->

          </div>
      <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <!-- End Repeater --> 
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

This code isn't tested, but it should at least point in you in the right direction :)

Comment: Yes, you are right - What i done as follow :    
1)  i created a costum post type named "portfolio"    
2)  i created the 3 categories for the post type    
3)  i created a simple text field from ACF named "category-name" and set this as - taxonomy is equal to category.   
4)  inside the category (for every category) i write the text ,the name of the class eventually.   
5)  Now i want to get the value what i wrote in the field as a class.  

I was follow your instruction step by step - Nothing...several tests the var_dump show me it was NULL , i don't know what am i missing out here ??

Comment: A few questions to try debug the problem: 1. Was the code you posted working (except for the class name)? 2. What does a var_dump of `$categories` show after this line? `$categories = get_the_category( get_the_ID());` 3. is the value of `get_the_ID()` the correct post id?

Comment: 1)  yes, the repeater is working and i success to render all the posts with the repeater within. 2)  i was try to post here the all array - object(WP_Term)#7882 (16) ,but i can't post it here..may i maybe can send to you via email? 3) from the function get_the_ID() i recieve integer for example: int(2243) , the number is the id of the post

Comment: $category_classes give me an empty string

Comment: That’s because you are not using *categories* like you said you were, you are using a *custom taxonomy* which is different! The rest of the answer is correct, so you just need to use the right function to get the taxonomy terms (not categories :) )

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are saving a custom field with the name `project-name` in a variable:

```
$projectDescription = get_sub_field('project-name');
```

Maybe you should change this meta key of the subfield to "project-description", it might be confusing, if you also have the name of a project.

To output a value in php you use `<?php echo $variableName; ?>`

You are accessing the values in a repeater called `portfolio-projects-repeater`. So your fields are inside of this and need to be accessed using a while, like you did.

**Your screenshot shows a text field, which is not inside a repeater field.**

So if you want to get the value of that field, you just need to use `get_field()`. This do not need to be in a while and not be called by using `get_sub_field`.

Your code therefore should look like:

```
    $variableName = get_field('category-name');
```

After saving to variable, you can simply output it with:

```
<div class="grid-item-catalog catalog-project-Holder <?php echo $variableName; ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you , but you are wrong...it is not connected to the repeater, i try to get the text field value from the category of the post type

Answer (score 0):

Yaaaayyy... I succeeded, with this code:

```
         <?php
            // load all 'category' terms for the post
            $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');
            // we will use the first term to load ACF data from
            if( !empty($terms) ) {
                $term = array_pop($terms);
                $custom_field = get_field('category-name', $term );
            }
          ?>
```

In any case i want to thank you for all yours reply's , i am very appreciat this.

Comment: Hi FluffyKitten,
Sorry about my long delay....

I am accept your answer as you asked to me....there are yet several issues that make me very confused and i need to understand...you know every day learning somthing. Thank You !!!

Answer (score 0):

**Create A Template in the theme and then use the below code, Just change the slug (banner_image)**

```
<?php
    //Get the Post ID
    $id = get_the_ID();
?>

    <img src="<?php echo get_field('banner_image', $id); ?>" />
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center"><?php echo get_field( "banner_heading", $id); ?></div>
```